# Is a subset of a boundary closed?

Tags: general-topology

I know that the boundary of a set $A \subset X$ is closed. Is it also true that a subset of a boundary is closed?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: No. Is every subset of a closed set closed?

Comment: @T.Bongers Not every closed set is a boundary.

Comment: No, I know it is not true in the general case, just thought if there was an exception in the case of a boundary.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, but it's a good starting point to address whether it's reasonable to expect a yes answer.

Comment: Why would it be?  subsets of closed sets aren't closed in general, so why would the set being a boundary j force its subsets to be closed.  Consider A={(x,y)|y $le $ 2}.  Its boundary is the line y=2.  This line will have a subset (0,1)x {2}.  Which is not closed.  Consider any boundary A with more than one point and at least on limit point,a.  Consider A/a.  That can't be closed.

Comment: Boundaries are closed but have empty interior and have no open subsets.  So that makes it reasonable to think boundaries have exception.  But not open doesn't mean closed so, as with most closed sets, taking a subset that doesn't include all limit points (assuming there were limit points and multiple points) will result in a subset that isn't closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: $$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq  \partial \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the set $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ in two-space and the subset of the boundary
$$
T=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1,y>0\}
$$
This set is not closed, because $(1,0)$ belongs to the closure, but not to $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a boundary with at least two points and at least one limit point.  (Finding such a boundary is trivial.  The unit circle in Euclidean plane will do.)  Let $a $ be one of the limit points.  Then $a$ is a limit point of the set A-{$a $}.  So the set $A-{a}\subset A $ is not closed.

Closed subsets, in general (not always, of course-- sets of isolated points, which have no limit points would be an exception), will usually have subsets that are not closed.    Boundaries are no different.